# Grep the word with multiple spaces

Tags: sed, grep

I am trying to grep the below text from a file and trying to uncomment the same with sed command. please help

```
#auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid
```

Need to grep and remove `#` for exact same line using sed

Comment: Honestly, this is why so many daemons now have `.d` subdirectories that they include configs from. `pam` uses `/etc/pam.d` where you can drop in a file with the uncommented version and you'll get what you want. (Left as a comment because it doesn't answer the actual question.)

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco not always helpful though, since many PAM entries are order sensitive

Answer (score 2):

I have used the patch command for things like this.

Make a backup copy of the file, make the edit with a normal editor, then use `diff -u file.bak file > file.patch` to generate the patch.

Then you can apply the patch with `patch -p0 file.patch` next time (you may need to change `-p0` if you use a full path name.

This is easier than generating an exact sed line and somewhat safer, as if the file doesn't match, the patch will fail rather than mangling the file.   This works for multi-line changes as well.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/^#(auth[[:space:]]+required[[:space:]]+pam_wheel\.so use_uid[[:space:]]*)$/\1/' file
```

If the output looks correct, then you could add `-i` option to edit the file directly.